# How to do the "users who like X also like Y" query?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm

Say I have a table for products, for users, and for "likes" for products made by users. Something like this:

```
create table likes (
user_id int unsigned not null,
product_id int unsigned not null,
rating set('like','dislike') not null,
primary key (user_id, product_id)
);
```

On the page for a particular product, I want to query the "likes" table to find a few other products that were "liked" by the users who also liked this particular product. What would this query look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query to find the products most liked by users who also like `product_id=x`:

```
select L2.product_id, count(L2.user_id) as num_users from likes L1
join likes L2
where L1.product_id=x and L1.rating='like'
and L2.user_id = L1.user_id
group by L2.product_id
order by num_users desc;
```

Comment: This is very clear and simple.

Comment: Thank you, indeed it's very clear. Would you mind also adding which indexes I should make in order to optimize this query, in case the `likes` table gets millions of rows? Would I place a multi-column index on `product_id, rating` in this case?

Comment: Yes, add an index on `user_id` as well.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use an inner query to do this

```
select l.product_id, count(u.user_id) as like_number
from (select user_id from likes where product_id=<product_id> and rating="like") as u
inner join likes as l on u.user_id=l.user_id
where l.rating="like"
group by l.product_id
having count(u.user_id) > <number>
order by like_number
```

the having clause means only products liked by more than a certain number of users can be suggested